# Modify a column in Spark dataframe based on certain conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, transformation

I want to transform the clientIPInt(which is in Int format, duh!) to a separate column after applying certain formulas on it.

```
Sample Input: df_A
    +----+------------------------+
    |num |clientIPInt             |
    +----+------------------------+
    |1275|200272593               |
    |145 |200172593               |
    |2678|200274543               |
    |6578|200272593               |
    |1001|200272593               |
    +----+------------------------+
Output:

+----+------------------------++---------------+
|num |clientIPInt             |ip64bigint      |
+----+------------------------+----------------+
|1275|200272593               |3521834763      |
|145 |0                       |0               |
|2678|200272593               |3521834763      |
|6578|200272593               |3521834763      |
|1001|200272593               |3521834763      |         
+----+------------------------+----------------+
```

I created an udf to do the transformation. Below is what I tried.

```
val b = df_A.withColumn("ip64bigint", ipToLong(df_A.col("clientIpInt")))
val ipToLong = udf{(ipInt: Int) =>
    val i = {
      if (ipInt <= 0) ipInt.toLong + 4294967296L
      else ipInt.toLong
    }
    val b = ((i & 255L) * 16777216L) + ((i & 65280L) * 256L) + ((i & 16711680L) / 256L) + ((i / 16777216L) & 255L)
    b
  }
```

However this udf is not as performant.

Next I tried using a column function, but the below code doesn't work

```
val d = df_A.withColumn("ip64bigint", newCol($"clientIpInt"))
def newCol(col: Column): Column = {
    when(col <= 0, ((((col.toLong + + 4294967296L) & 255L) * 16777216L) + (((col.toLong + + 4294967296L) & 65280L) * 256L) + (((col.toLong + + 4294967296L) & 16711680L) / 256L) + (((col.toLong + + 4294967296L) / 16777216L) & 255L))).
      otherwise(((col & 255L) * 16777216L) + ((col & 65280L) * 256L) + ((col & 16711680L) / 256L) + ((col / 16777216L) & 255L))
  }
```

I don't really want to convert the dataframe df_A to Dataset[case class of columns], since I have more than 140 columns in the dataframe..

Any ideas what am I doing wrong with the column function or any other way of transforming the data

Comment: Any ideas @Shaido ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one solution that is working:

example dataframe =>

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val data =
  Seq(
    Row(1275, 200272593),
    Row(145, 0),
    Row(2678, 200274543),
    Row(6578, 200272593),
    Row(1001, 200272593))

val dF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  StructType(List(StructField("num", IntegerType, nullable = true),
    StructField("clientIPInt", IntegerType, nullable = true))))
```

```
+----+-----------+
| num|clientIPInt|
+----+-----------+
|1275|  200272593|
| 145|          0|
|2678|  200274543|
|6578|  200272593|
|1001|  200272593|
+----+-----------+
```

using spark provided functions =>

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
dF.withColumn("i", when('clientIPInt <= 0, ('clientIPInt cast "long") + 4294967296L).otherwise('clientIPInt cast "long"))
    .withColumn("ip64bigint", (('i.bitwiseAND(255L) * 16777216L) + ('i.bitwiseAND(65280L) * 256L) + ('i.bitwiseAND(16711680L) / 256L) + ('i / 16777216L).cast("long").bitwiseAND(255L)) cast "long")
       .drop("i").show(false)
```

Output =>

```
+----+-----------+----------+
|num |clientIPInt|ip64bigint|
+----+-----------+----------+
|1275|200272593  |3521834763|
|145 |0          |0         |
|2678|200274543  |1878191883|
|6578|200272593  |3521834763|
|1001|200272593  |3521834763|
+----+-----------+----------+
```